# Livescript's clone operator ^^ doesn't work in the server side (node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, livescript

In `livescript`, we can use `^^` to clone an object.

For example,

```
consloe.log (^^{a:1})
```

will be compiled to

```
// Generated by LiveScript 1.2.0
(function(){
  console.log(clone$({
    a: 1
  }));
  function clone$(it){
    function fun(){} fun.prototype = it;
    return new fun;
  }
}).call(this);
```

However, these codes work successfully in browser but not in node.js.

- In browser, it prints `fun {a: 1}` in console.
- In node.js, it shows nothing.

What's the reason?

Comment: I have tried to test this in browser and node.js, every time I get an empty object {} with _proto_ set to {a: 1} . Even by looking at the generated script and livescript website: ^^ clones only the prototype not the hasOwnProperty(s). You may want to review <<< operator in livescript which may perform your desired task.

Comment: @Nitin... post that as an answer :).

Comment: Livescript doesn't compile that to `Object.create`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does console.log() only print member fields?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21104397/why-does-console-log-only-print-member-fields)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Properties of prototypes are not printed out by default. The `^^` operator sets the operand as the prototype of a new object. The properties are still are still accessible, but won't be printed by `console.log` and won't be serialized into JSON.

If you simply want to copy over properties, use `{} <<< obj`.