# Why does console.log() only print member fields?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

If I run the following:

```
var T = function(x, y) {
   this.x = x;
   this.y = y;
}

T.prototype.foo = function() {
   console.log("test");
}

var o = new T(7,4);

o.foo();
console.log(o);
```

using `node` I get:

```
test
{x: 7, y: 4}
```

but if I run it in chrome I get:

```
test
T {x: 7, y: 4, foo: function}
```

Is this just a variation in the implementation of the `log()` method or why are `prototype` methods ignored in the output? If its not just a `log()` implementation case, does this mean it would be safe to save objects containing both fields and methods into a `mongodb` if you only wanted to save the fields, i.e., can you rely on the methods not being considered?

Comment: Sry, actually this is not a duplicate - the reason for not-printed properties is a very different one :-/ If at all, it should be marked as a duplicate of [Why does console.log() not show inherited properties from Object.create?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13300863/1048572) which however does not have good answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`console.log` is implemented differently in different environments.  And that's because what it does only makes sense in the context of the tools that its result are viewed through.  In Chrome you have an inspector and can drill into the object.  In node, it outputs text to the command line, where you have far less capability.

This is purely an implementation detail within `console.log` and you should *not* use the difference of implementations to assume anything about how object properties work in other contexts, like say... writing objects to mongodb.

Answer (score 1):

It is just a log implementation difference (actually more accurately it is an inspect difference).